# How to let give an IAM role access to read and write from an Elasticache Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-iam, amazon-elasticache

I have an ElastiCache memcached cluster.
I know how to allow access to a security group, so it can access the cache.
However, I wish to allow such an access to an IAM role.
Specifically I'm running an ElasticMapReduce job, and I want to allow the task nodes to access the cache, using the EC2_DEFAULT_ROLE IAM role.

How do I do that?